# Backbone.js error when trying to set model attribute to same value

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I keep getting the same error when I try to set an attribute but only if the attribute's value already the same as the value I am trying to set it to:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (obj) { return new wrapper(obj); } has no method 'has'
```

For example I have the following line:

```
var s = new SampleModel({"language": "en"});
s.set("language", "en") // this produces the above error
```

Anyone have any insight into this problem? I am currently using the most recent version of Backbone.js 0.9.1

Comment: are you including the underscore.js library?

Comment: To expand @ggreiner comment, do you include underscore.js 1.3.1? _.has has been added in the latest release http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#changelog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ggreiner and @nikoshr are right... they should have posted answers instead of comments, though.

this error is caused by having an outdated version of Underscore.js. you need to upgrade it to v1.3.1 for use with Backbone v0.9.x

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/

Comment: Thank you Derick, you were all 100% correct I had upgraded to a new version of Backbone.js without updating to the newest version of underscore (v1.3.1 is required).